# Extracting numbers after a word and storing the results as a new line separator "\n"

Tags: r, regex

I have some text data which looks like:

```
text
1  to $2.00 on an ongoing basis. the ongoing eps guidance excludes both a 68 cent-per-share charge associated with the establishment of the solutia-related reserve and a tax benefit of
2     wheat and barley business. on a reported basis, eps is in the range of $1.56 to $1.71 per share for the full fiscal year. (for a reconciliation of ongoing... eps was 4.56 to 4.98
3                                    the year ago quarter while 2004 full year eps was $.93, up 7.7% from 2003. return on equity was 21.7% for the fourth quarter and 20.4% for the full
```

I am trying to extract some information from it. I want to extract the first number after the word `eps`. I can do the following:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(
    firstNumberAfterWord = str_match_all(text, "eps\\D*(\\d+)")
  )
```

Which gives:

```
                 firstNumberAfterWord
1 eps guidance excludes both a 68, 68
2        eps is in the range of $1, 1    # This is wrong. It should be "$1.56 to $1.71"
3                    eps was $.93, 93
```

Which does not do what I want since it pulls `68`, `1` and `93` but the `1` is incorrect. I have looked at `map_chr(myWordColumn, str_c, collapse = "\n"),` to first collapse it and then extract the words but without luck.

I  want to extract the first digits after the `eps` word (all occurrences of the `eps` word where each occurrence is separated by a `"\n"` separator.

Expected output would be to have a new column which contains:

```
$.93 # since this comes after the part "eps was $.93"
68 # since it comes after "eps guidance excludes both a 68"
$1.56 to $ 1.71 # "eps is in the range of $1.56 to $1.71" # On a new line for this observation
 4.56 to 4.98 # eps was 4.56 to 4.98
```

Which all come after the `eps` word.

Data:

```
    data <- data.frame(
  text = c(" to $2.00 on an ongoing basis. the ongoing eps guidance excludes both a 68 cent-per-share charge associated with the establishment of the solutia-related reserve and a tax benefit of", 
           " wheat and barley business. on a reported basis, eps is in the range of $1.56 to $1.71 per share for the full fiscal year. (for a reconciliation of ongoing... eps was 4.56 to 4.98",
           " the year ago quarter while 2004 full year eps was $.93, up 7.7% from 2003. return on equity was 21.7% for the fourth quarter and 20.4% for the full"
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the following pattern:

```
\beps\b\D*?(\p{Sc}?\d*\.?\d+(?:\s*(?:to|[\xAD\p{Pd}])\s*\d*\.?\d+)?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ePhrRR/2). **Details**

- `\beps\b` - a whole word `eps`
- `\D*?` - 0 or more non-digit chars, as few as possible
- `(\p{Sc}?\d*\.?\d+(?:\s*(?:to|\p{Pd})\s*\d*\.?\d+)?)` - Group 1:

  - `\p{Sc}?` - an optional currency symbol
  - `\d*\.?\d+` - an integer or float number
  - `(?:\s*(?:to|[\xAD\p{Pd}])\s*\d*\.?\d+)?` - an optional occurrence of

    - `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
    - `(?:to|[\xAD\p{Pd}])` - either `to` or any Unicode dash
    - `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
    - `\d*\.?\d+` - an integer or float number

See [an R demo](https://ideone.com/wavclP):

```
library(stringr)
data <- data.frame(
  text = c(" to $2.00 on an ongoing basis. the ongoing eps guidance excludes both a 68 cent-per-share charge associated with the establishment of the solutia-related reserve and a tax benefit of", 
           " wheat and barley business. on a reported basis, eps is in the range of $1.56 to $1.71 per share for the full fiscal year. (for a reconciliation of ongoing... eps was 4.56 to 4.98",
           " the year ago quarter while 2004 full year eps was $.93, up 7.7% from 2003. return on equity was 21.7% for the fourth quarter and 20.4% for the full"
  )
)
res <- str_match_all(data$text, "\\beps\\b\\D*?(\\p{Sc}?\\d*\\.?\\d+(?:\\s*(?:to|[\\xAD\\p{Pd}])\\s*\\d*\\.?\\d+)?)")
data$result <- lapply(res, function(x) paste(x[,-1], collapse="\n"))
```

Output:

```
text
1  to $2.00 on an ongoing basis. the ongoing eps guidance excludes both a 68 cent-per-share charge associated with the establishment of the solutia-related reserve and a tax benefit of
2     wheat and barley business. on a reported basis, eps is in the range of $1.56 to $1.71 per share for the full fiscal year. (for a reconciliation of ongoing... eps was 4.56 to 4.98
3                                    the year ago quarter while 2004 full year eps was $.93, up 7.7% from 2003. return on equity was 21.7% for the fourth quarter and 20.4% for the full
               result
1                  68
2 $1.56\n4.56 to 4.98
3                $.93
```